# In postgresql how to change the value in jsonb type cloumn?

Tags: postgresql, function, postgresql-9.4

Now I want to use postgresql function  to change the jsonb type cloumn's value,now I have a function achieve the type json

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "json_object_set_key"(
  "json"          json,
  "key_to_set"    TEXT,
  "value_to_set"  anyelement
)
  RETURNS json
  LANGUAGE sql
  IMMUTABLE
  STRICT
AS $function$
SELECT COALESCE(
  (SELECT ('{' || string_agg(to_json("key") || ':' || "value", ',') || '}')
     FROM (SELECT *
             FROM json_each("json")
            WHERE "key" <> "key_to_set"
            UNION ALL
           SELECT "key_to_set", to_json("value_to_set")) AS "fields"),
  '{}'
)::json
$function$;
```

but I unable to change the json type to jsonb,Now I want a function "jsonb_object_set_key"  who can achieve, please help me,thank you very much.

Comment: Why don't you using `jsonb_set()`? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

Comment: Don't use raw string concatenation for building JSON. There's no reason to, and then you have to worry about escaping and quoting rules. This function would probably be simpler if written in pl/v8, too.

Comment: Which version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: I using postgresql 9.4

Answer (score -1):

just change the return data type:

```
t=# DROP FUNCTION jsonb_object_set_key(json,text,anyelement);
DROP FUNCTION
t=# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "jsonb_object_set_key"(
t(#       "jsonb"          jsonb,
t(#       "key_to_set"    TEXT,
t(#       "value_to_set"  anyelement
t(#     )
t-#       RETURNS jsonb
t-#       LANGUAGE sql
t-#       IMMUTABLE
t-#       STRICT
t-#     AS $function$
t$#     SELECT COALESCE(
t$#       (SELECT ('{' || string_agg(to_json("key") || ':' || "value", ',') || '}')
t$#          FROM (SELECT *
t$#                  FROM jsonb_each("jsonb")
t$#                 WHERE "key" <> "key_to_set"
t$#                 UNION ALL
t$#                SELECT "key_to_set", to_jsonb("value_to_set")) AS "fields"),
t$#       '{}'
t$#     )::jsonb
t$#     $function$;
CREATE FUNCTION
```

here it goes:

```
t=# select pg_typeof(jsonb_object_set_key('{"a":3}','a',5));
 jsonb
```

alse if you have at least 9.5 concider using `jsonb_set`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

Comment: when I change '{"a":3}' to jsonb type , it can not work :

Comment: when I change '{"a":3}' to jsonb type , it can not work :
select  pg_typeof(jsonb_object_set_key(jsonb_in('{"a":3}'),jsonb_in('{"a":3}') ->>'a',5))

Comment: It is still can not run